# Can't open .tex files after update

Tags: texlive, texworks

When I installed LaTeX I followed an online guide a bit blindly, so forgive me if I mix up things.

I just updated TeX Live (via TeX Live Manager in the command line) and now I can't open `.tex` files with TeXworks. When I double click in the files, nothing happens, same thing when I try to start a new `texworks.exe` process, it simply doesn't do anything.

Updating TeX Live was the only thing I did, and before this it all worked perfectly and without issue.

What could be causing this problem?

Comment: Welcome! Which online guide? I guess you're using Windows and TeXworks came bundled as part of TeX Live? TeX Live Manager probably produced a `.log` file and probably also saved the old versions of packages to backup. Did you get any errors? Is there anything in the log?

Comment: probably missing file associations. can you open `*.tex`files with any editor (e.g. notepad, notepad++)?

Comment: @cfr Sorry, I don't remember which guide. Yes, you're right, texworks came bundled. The log file doesn't say anything special. It failed the first time because the program was still open (a common mistake for beginners) and then it just did a "self restore" and a "self update". naphaneal Yeah, the .tex files I can open without issue with notepad, I guess I should have specified that in the title. It's just texworks/texlive not responding.

Comment: @naphaneal Not if opening the `.exe` directly fails, too? Would reinstalling the editor help? Presumably, TeX Live has a package for TeXworks which could be reinstalled? (I don't use Windows, so TeX Live doesn't bundle an editor for me.)

Comment: @cfr sounds like a borked update. I'd try a repair install first. if that fails, clean reinstall (uninstall, if possible, delete otherwise, use `ccleaner` or `WiseClean` to clean registry of zombie entries.)

Comment: @naphaneal It was, I updated every package via TexLive Manager and now it works again, although I don't know which package in particular was causing problems, but it definitely wasn't just texworks. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @naphaneal An answer?

Answer (score 2):

Blindly following obscure guide lines often leads to `b0rK3d!#"` update procedures or installations. If that is the case, try the following:

- Try a repair of the installed program and update any installed package.
- If that fails, try to uninstall the program.

  - If the uninstall fails, delete the installed folders manually. Use <del>*ccleaner* or</del> *Wise Disk Cleaner* to get rid of zombie entries in the Windows registry.
- Install the latest TeX Live environment and LaTeX editor/IDE to your liking, but as clean as possible.

Comment: Please do not use CCleaner as it is known for breaking Windows.

Comment: @genodeftest I'm using it so far without problems. but I'm using WIN7, which will stay until I switch to *nixoid OS soon. I recommend WiseClean instead.